# How to free 2D dynamic array in C

Tags: arrays, c, free

I have this part in my C code.

```
char** argv_list = parse_cmdline(input);
```

parse_cmdline() returns also 2D array. I want to free the argv_list. How to find the rows size of argv_list to free it like this :

```
for(int r = 0 ; r < rows ; r++)
{
   free(argv_list[r]);
}

free(argv_list);
```

Comment: Well, you have to keep track of it, or set a maximum.

Comment: @vmt I can't. My teacher told me to find it in the same way of strlen(). But i got errors

Comment: In order to do that you must allocate space for n+1 elements (well, pointers in this case) and set the last one to NULL in `parse_cmdline()`. When you free it, loop over it until you encounter the NULL pointer.

Comment: `strlen()` can't help you here.

Answer (score 2):

In C language, arrays are not first class objects. (This means C does not support arrays in all the ways it supports objects generally. For example, you cannot assign a “value” to an entire array.) When you pass an array to a function, or when a function returns an array, they *decay* to a pointer to their first element. Said differently, you have no way to know the original size.

Common ways are either to use an auxilliary integer variable (pass a pointer to it) to return the length, or to use a *sentinel* value to mark the end of the array. This latter convention is used in C strings, that are character arrays where the last used character is a null character. It is also use in `argv` (the second parameter of `main`) where the last used arg is a null pointer.

Here, as the function returns a pointer to strings (in fact a pointer to pointers), the most common way is to define the last used element of the array to be a NULL pointer, respecting `argv` convention.

Comment: Re “In C language, arrays are not first class objects”: This is jargon—terminology that will not be known to a student and so will not be understood without explanation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I hoped the next sentence (when you pass...) to be the explaination. But according to your comment, I have failed... The problem is that my English does not allow me to provide a more clean and simple explaination. Feel free to edit my post if you want. I could even make it a community wiki.

Comment: All that is needed is a little definition. I added one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the length of dynamically allocated arrays in C (2D or otherwise). If you need that information save it to a variable (or at least a way to calculate it) when the memory is initially allocated and pass the pointer to the memory and the size of the memory around together.

What you need to do is to keep track of the lenght of the array each time the `malloc()` function is called.

Or you can use a different approach as suggested by **vmt** in comment section you can explicitly append a sentinel value at the end of your array each time you make a call to `malloc()` function then later on that array you can loop until to the sentinel to get the array size.

Then you can use

```
sizeof(array_size)/sizeof(array[0])
```

this code in order to get the row number and then use it in your code.

Comment: Well yes you can if you use a sentinel

Comment: @vmt yes of course, one way of achieving the result is to use a sentinel value (NULL)

Comment: Beware, `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) only makes sense with true arrays, and not with pointers...

Comment: consider rolling back the edit regarding the use of `sizeof`